# Shiny app - adjust output based on input using conditional panels

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am very new to Shiny app and R and would appreciate any advice! I am creating an app that performs a calculation and outputs a plot based on several inputs. Right now, I have an input called "Clustered" in a conditional Panel (a checkbox), and when a user selects it, a few other inputs become available. For now, my output (the plot) changes correctly based on the new inputs (ICC, cluster_size) when selecting the "Cluster" checkbox. However, the issue I am having is that it doesn't update when a user tries to change the values of inputs that are used in both conditional panels.

My UI code looks like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Font ----
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      h2 {
        font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
      }"))
  ),
             
  # App title ----
  titlePanel(div("XXXXXXX", style = "color: #E35925")),
  
  # Top panel -----
  fluidRow(
   column(3, # size of box
          selectInput("alpha",
                    "Significance Level",
                     c("Alpha = 0.01",
                       "Alpha = 0.05",
                       "Alpha = 0.10"),
                        selected = "Alpha = 0.05")
  ), 
  
  column(3, numericInput( 'power', 'Power', .8, min = 0.1, max = 1, step = .1))
  ), 
    
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-weight: bolder;
      }"))
      ),
      
    
      
      # Input: Binary outcome ------- 
      checkboxInput(inputId = "binary", 
                    label = "Binary Outcome", 
                    value = FALSE, 
                    width = NULL),
      
      # Input: Clustered design ------- 
      checkboxInput(inputId = "cluster", 
                    label = "Clustered Design", 
                    value = FALSE, 
                    width = NULL),
      
      
      ####### First Panel: No cluster & continous outcome #########
      conditionalPanel(
        condition ="input.cluster == false & input.binary == false",
      
        # Input: Power level -------------
      #sliderInput(inputId = "power", label = "Power:", min = 0, max = 1, value = .8),step = )  if you want to specify step size
    
      # Input: min and max MDE ---------- 
        numericInput('MDE_min', 'Minimum Detectable Effect (min)', .1, min = 0, max = 10),
        numericInput('MDE_max', 'Minimum Detectable Effect (max)', .4, min = 0, max = 10),
        # numericInput('MDE_scale', 'Minimum Detectable Effect (scale)', .02, min = 0, max = 10),
        #numericInput('propT', 'Proportion in Treatment', .5, min = 0, max = 1)
      
      # Input: Standard Deviation -------------
      numericInput('SD', 
                   'Standard Deviation of the Outcome', 
                   .4, min = 0, 
                   max = 1000000, 
                   step = .1),
      
      # Input: Proportion in Treatment ---
      sliderInput(inputId = "propT",
                  label = "Proportion in Treatment",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 1,
                  value = .5)
      
        ), # First conditional panel ends ------------------------------------

    
    # Second panel: Clustered and continous outcome ----------
    conditionalPanel(
      condition ="input.cluster == true & input.binary == false",
      
      # Inputs:
      numericInput('MDE_min', 'Minimum Detectable Effect (min)', .1, min = 0, max = 10),
      numericInput('MDE_max', 'Minimum Detectable Effect (max)', .4, min = 0, max = 10),
      numericInput('SD', 'Standard Deviation of the Outcome', .4, min = 0, max = 1000000, 
                   step = .1),
      sliderInput(inputId = "propT", label = "Proportion in Treatment",
                  min = 0, max = 1, value = .5),
      sliderInput(inputId = "ICC", label = "Intracluster Correlation",
                  min = 0, max = 1, value = .2),
      numericInput('cluster_size', 'Cluster Size', 20, min = 0, max = 1000000, 
                   step = 1),
    )
    ), 
    
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Power Plot ----
      plotOutput(outputId = "powerPlot")
      
    )
  )
)
```

From what I have looked up already, this may be due to my inputs having the same IDs? How can I use these same input IDs while getting the mutual inputs in both panels to update after  "Clustered" is selected. From what I have read, reactive expressions may help here -- but I tried these and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate any advice!

Below is the rest of my code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$powerPlot <- renderPlot({

    #------- Create function - No Clusters --------#
    SS_function = function(MDE, propT, SD){7.84*((SD^2)/(((propT*(1-propT))*(MDE*MDE))))}
    MDE = seq(input$MDE_min, input$MDE_max, by=((input$MDE_max-input$MDE_min)*.05))
    propT = input$propT
    SD = input$SD
    sample_size=SS_function(MDE, propT, SD)
    
    #------- Create function - With Clusters ------#
    SS_function_cl = function(MDE, propT, SD, cluster_size, ICC)
    { (SD^2*(1+(cluster_size-1))*ICC) / 
        (cluster_size * (MDE/2.802)^2 * (propT*(1-propT)))
    }
    
    MDE = seq(input$MDE_min, input$MDE_max, by=((input$MDE_max-input$MDE_min)*.05))
    propT = input$propT
    SD = input$SD
    ICC = input$ICC
    cluster_size = input$cluster_size
    N_clusters = SS_function_cl(MDE, propT, SD, cluster_size, ICC)
    sample_size_cl= cluster_size * N_clusters # should be times 2?
    
    #----------- Create plot ------------#
    if (input$cluster %in% "FALSE") {
    data <- data.frame(MDE,sample_size)
    data %>% ggplot(aes(x=sample_size, y=MDE)) +
      geom_line(aes(color="E35925")) +
      geom_point(aes(color="E35925")) +
      theme(legend.position="none",
            axis.text=element_text(size=12),
            axis.title=element_text(size=14), 
            text = element_text(family = "Century Gothic")) +
      labs(y= "MDE", x = "Sample Size") 
    
    } else {
      data <- data.frame(MDE,sample_size_cl)
      data %>% ggplot(aes(x=sample_size_cl, y=MDE)) +
        geom_line(aes(color="E35925")) +
        geom_point(aes(color="E35925")) +
        theme(legend.position="none",
              axis.text=element_text(size=12),
              axis.title=element_text(size=14), 
              text = element_text(family = "Century Gothic")) +
        labs(y= "MDE", x = "Sample Size") 
  
    }
      

  }) # output ends

} # server function ends


######################################
#         Create Shiny app           #
######################################
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried adding reactive expressions but struggled to get them to run properly.

Comment: A single Shiny widget cannot appear in more than one place (that is, on two or more `conditionalPanels`).  Every widget *must* have a unique ID. That is the source of your problem.  Either remove the common widgets from both `conditionalPanel`s and display them unconditionally (the most logical solution) or rename them so that their IDs are unique and adjust your server code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much! That solved my issue -- I hadn't realized it could be that simple.